# pandas dataframe character columns to integer

Tags: python, pandas

I have my dataframe like below:

```
+--------------+--------------+----+-----+-------+
|      x1      |      x2      | km | gmm | class |
+--------------+--------------+----+-----+-------+
|  180.9863129 | -0.266379416 | 24 |  19 | T     |
|  52.20132828 |  28.93587875 | 16 |  14 | I     |
| -17.17127419 |  29.97013283 | 17 |  16 | D     |
|  37.28710938 | -69.96691132 |  3 |   6 | N     |
| -132.2395782 |  27.02541733 | 15 |  18 | G     |
| -12.52811623 | -87.90951538 | 22 |   5 | S     |
```

The classes are basically alphabets(A to Z). However, I want the output like A=1, B=2... Z= 26.

Now, for normal python list, I can convert them like `ord(c.lower()) - ord('a')) % 9) + 1`

However, how to do that in a dataframe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1**
Assuming your column *only* has single, uppercase characters, you can do a little arithmetic on the `view`:

```
df['class'] = df['class'].values.astype('<U1').view(np.uint32) - 64

df
           x1         x2  km  gmm  class
0  180.986313  -0.266379  24   19     20
1   52.201328  28.935879  16   14      9
2  -17.171274  29.970133  17   16      4
3   37.287109 -69.966911   3    6     14
4 -132.239578  27.025417  15   18      7
5  -12.528116 -87.909515  22    5     19
```

This is the fastest method I can think of *for large data*.

If there is the chance you have erratic data, you may consider a preprocessing step like this:

```
df['class'] = df['class'].str.upper().str[0]
```

---

**Option 2**
`ord`

```
df['class'] = [ord(c) - 64 for c in df['class']]
```

Or,

```
df['class'] = df['class'].apply(ord) - 64
```

```
df
           x1         x2  km  gmm  class
0  180.986313  -0.266379  24   19     20
1   52.201328  28.935879  16   14      9
2  -17.171274  29.970133  17   16      4
3   37.287109 -69.966911   3    6     14
4 -132.239578  27.025417  15   18      7
5  -12.528116 -87.909515  22    5     19
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `string` here with `map`

```
import string
df['class'].map(dict(zip(list(string.ascii_uppercase),list(range(1,27)))))
Out[1155]: 
0    20
1     9
2     4
3    14
4     7
5    19
Name: class, dtype: int64
```